# MVC Core - redirect to login on certain API response (authentication required)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried to find a good solution, but have not found so far, so asking for advice.

I have MVC Core 'website' project + MVC Core 'API' project.
Website speaks to API and uses bearer token. When user authenticates at Website - it sends authentication request to API as well. Api sends bearer token back that is valid for some time. Website encapsulates bearer token to cookie and sends it to end user. When end user works with website, the website checks if user is authenticated basing on cookie.

Website cannot work without API and sends all requests that way. At some point API can return exception that indicates that bearer token is expired. So when website receives it - it needs to redirect user to login page again, so we get a new bearer token and a new cookie.

The question is how this could be done in a generic way. We do not know that bearer token is expired until we send request to API. So this situation could happen at any controller and any action.

What I currently have is a code like:

```
var apiResponse = await apiCommunicator.GetResponse(endpoint, content);
```

GetResponse returns entity like `<Response<T>>` - where Response is a generic class that contains all basic information about response (contains error, valid, etc.) and T - class that encapsulates data that we need from this API call.

I can easily extend Response class to include something like `IsAuthenticationRequired` flag. But the question is how could I finally make redirect in a flexible way.

**Solution 1**

Simple checking for this flag above and make RedirectToAction. But that does not look good as I need always to check it and duplicate code on each request. Easy to make mistake.

**Solution 2**

Implement exception that could be caught by a middleware. If middleware detects that exception is of type X - make redirect.
In this way middleware would look like

```
try
{
   await _next.Invoke(context);
}
catch(MyAuthenticationException ex)
{ ... }
```

But that does not look too good as well - what if inside one of controllers the call to apiCommunicator would be surrounded by try-catch as well? In this case middleware would not catch anything.

**Solution 3 - best choice so far**

Issue website cookie to the period that is less than bearer token validity period. So far it looks like a best choice. But is this really the best way?

Any ideas about how this could be flexibly accomplished would be highly appreciated!

Comment: In my view, the first and third solution you mentioned would be fine. Besides, you make request(s) to Web API with acquired token within your website code logic, it would response 401 if token is expired, HTTP 401 is not exception, so the second solution not make sense.